# jpql INTERSECT without INTERSECT

Tags: sql, jpql

i have four queries that return intergers.

```
select listOfIntegers from [something]...
```

(**edit:** the results are ROWS)

and need a way to do

```
select ...
intersect
select ...
intersect
select ...
intersect
select ...
```

but in jpql there is no intersect as such.

so, is there a way to mimic the behavior using some other jpql to get the same result?

(for those that are unsure about intersect) basically i need to get all the values that appear in ALL the selects...

```
result from select 1: 1,2,3,4
result from select 2: 1,2,5,6
result from select 3: 1,2,7,8
result from select 4: 1,2,9,0

so the result i want with intersect: 1,2
```

thnx a lot

p.s. there is no chance to use ANYHTING OTHER THAN JPQL :( no native queries, etc...

Comment: That result are rows or columns ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use something like this?:

```
select s1.result
  from select_1 as s1
 where exists (
               select *
                 from select_2 as s2
                where s2.result = s1.result
              )
       and exists (
                   select *
                     from select_3 as s3
                    where s3.result = s1.result
                  )
       and exists (
                   select *
                     from select_4 as s4
                    where s4.result = s1.result
                  );
```